# Show different phone numbers based on referrer, useragent

Tags: javascript, bots, referrer, user-agent

I am attempting to serve different phone numbers on a site based on a number of factors, allowing us to track inbound phone calls based on how users arrived at the page.

1. Check to see if user is coming from advertising by checking for "?provider=" querystring, serve advertising number if present
2. If not, check userAgent to serve "default" number to bots
3. If userAgent is not a bot, check referrer and serve different tracking number based on common SERP clicks

This site is unable to run server-side scripting so this has to be done with javascript (which I am fairly inexperienced with). I've cobbled together bits and pieces but ultimately would like to combine everything and have it work together in a single .js file that can be called on page load.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Querystring to check if paid session or organic
     function providercheck() {
        var str= location.href;
            if (str.indexOf("?provider=") > -1) {
                document.write("paid phone number");
            }
            else {
                botcheck();
            }
    }

    //Check userAgent to serve organic number to bots
     function botcheck() { 
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("googlebot") <= -1) {
                    document.write("default phone number");
                }
            else {
                    refcheck();
                }
    }

    //Check for referrer and serve number based on last referrer
    function refcheck() {
        var last_referrer = document.referrer;
        if (last_referrer.indexOf("google") > -1) {
            document.write("google tracking number");
        }
        else if (last_referrer.indexOf("yahoo") > -1) {
            document.write("yahoo tracking number");
        }
        else {
            document.write("default number");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help or guidance is very appreciated. I also need to set a session cookie to continue to serve the same number until a user leaves the site, but wanted to get this working first

Comment: You should do this on the server.

Comment: I wish I could, but not only do I not have server access, I don't have the ability to run php scripts or the like.

Comment: @Sean change the server, no? Any client-side solution will be error-prone and also you'd expose all of your numbers via code. Do you really need *this*?

Comment: I'm working within the limitations of a CMS that serves hundreds of template sites and I'm unable to change/modify server settings. I'm ok with the numbers being exposed in the code as long as I'm serving up the "default" number for spiders/bots (via the useragent check). I know it's going to be an uphill battle and won't be bulletproof by any means, but it's what i've got to work with.

Comment: You don't really have those stray `</script>` closing tags sprinkled in there, do you?

Comment: @Pointy - thanks, copied these from a few different places and didn't format properly.

Comment: You aren't serving _anything_ to spiders / bots.  Spiders don't run Javascript.

Comment: Let me clarify - I want to be sure that the correct "default" phone number is what spiders/bots see so that they don't index any of the tracking numbers being served by the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

put this span somewhere on your page:

`<span id="phoneNumber">Superdefaultnumber</span>`

And then this code in a script tag in the head of your document:

```
var setNumber = function(){
    var spanNode = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
    if (!spanNode) {throw new Error("Unable to find span");}

    if (location.href.indexOf("?provider=") > -1) {
        spanNode.innerHTML = "paid phone number";
    }    

    //Check userAgent to serve organic number to bots
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("googlebot") <= -1) {
        spanNode.innerHTML = "default phone number";
    }

    //Check for referrer and serve number based on last referrer
    var last_referrer = document.referrer;
    if (last_referrer.indexOf("google") > -1) {
        spanNode.innerHTML = "google tracking number";
    }
    else if (last_referrer.indexOf("yahoo") > -1) {
        spanNode.innerHTML = "yahoo tracking number";
    }
    else {
        spanNode.innerHTML = "default number";
    }    
};


window.addEventListener("load", setNumber);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the thorough reply. This looks great, will test it out.